# Is possible paginate multiple arrays with templateView in different contexts?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am working on a view with 2 tabs, in each tab a different list should be displayed. Here's an example of views.py file.

```py
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        today = datetime.today()
        start_week = today - timedelta(today.weekday())
        end_week = start_week + timedelta(7)
        context['dayli_expirations'] = Member.objects.filter(
            expiration_date__day=today.day, 
            expiration_date__month=today.month, 
            expiration_date__year=today.year
        )
        context['weekly_expirations'] = Member.objects.filter(expiration_date__range=[start_week, end_week])

        return context
```

Comment: Where is you pagination?

Comment: I'm looking a way to do it